# ERD Into Class Diagrams

Tags: uml, class-diagram, erd

[image: ERD]
when I convert the above ERD into Class Diagram classes, I noticed the classes as below.

- student
- lecturer
- module
- user

**I need to know how to convert "LecturerHasModule" and "studentHasModule" entities into classes. I'm confused to select their attributes.**

Comment: You table `Lecture` is missing the last `r`, which changes it's meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more logical seems to have a class-association between *Module* and *Student* and between *Lecture(r)* and *Module*

[image]

Impossible to answer you about *teacherHasModule* because it does not appear in your question (may be a typo for *LecturerHasModule*)

Comment: Thank you very much dear. actually my question should be corrected as 'teacherHasModule' to 'LectureHasModule'.